# Create charts in workshop based on two objects

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

Is it possible to create bar charts in workshop based on two different object sets?
For example I have two objects set **Object A** and **Object B**, I want to create a 3-D bar chart with X-axis( a date column) coming from Object A and Y-axis showing count categories i.e. coming from Object B.
Edit - Object A is linked with Object B with 1-N link.

I didn't find anything in workshop itself and I was trying to do it with function based charts but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Going for [Functions backed Charts](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/widgets-chart/#function-aggregations-function-backed-layers) should work. The crux of the work is to figure out which computation you need in the function to obtain what you want from the raw objects.

Assuming a cardinality of the categories for Object A and Object B being low enough (<<10k, let's assume 100), you would likely (below is only pseudocode, untested):

1. perform an aggregation on Object A

```js
const datesGrouped = await objects.groupBy(e => e.date.byDays()).count();
// Note: the count doesn't matter here, all you want is a short list of all the dates of Object A
```

2. Iterate over each group of A and perform a computation for B

```js
// Define the result map
const resultMap = new FunctionsMap<string, TwoDimensionalAggregation<Double>>();

// Alternative: For each string of the buckets array provided as input
const promises = buckets.map(currBucket => this.getObjectBBreakdown(currBucket));

// Use Promise.all to parallelize async execution of helper function
const allResolvedPromises = await Promise.all(promises);

// Populate resultMap with bucket and calculated value
for (let i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++) {
    resultMap.set(buckets[i], allResolvedPromises[i]);
}
```

And you would have another function, which for a particular object A can get you the breakdown of Object Bs

```js
    @Function()
    private async getObjectBBreakdown(bucket: string): Promise<TwoDimensionalAggregation<Double>> {
        // Get the object A which maps to this bucket
        const startObjectAs = await Objects.search().objectAs().filter(o => o.date.exactMatch(bucket));
        // Pivot to the Object Bs
        const objectBGroups = startObjectAs.searchAroundObjectBs();

        // Compute the aggregation for this object set
        return await objectBGroups.groupBy(e => e.category.exactValue()).count()
    }
```

See [docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/optimize-performance/#optimizing-link-traversals)

3. then do something with both results directly in memory of the function to build your ThreeDimensionalAggregation. I don't have an example at hand for ThreeDimensional, but showing you a TwoDimensional:

```js
        // Create a TwoDimensionalAggregation from the resultMap
        const aggregation: TwoDimensionalAggregation<string> = {
            buckets: Array.from(resultMap.entries()).map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value })),
        };
```

Note: If you want a "3D Chart" as in "With volumes" you might want to look at [Vega plot](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/cards-vega-plot/) available in Quiver. The pre-requisite will likely be the same in terms of function computation, but this would offer you additional charts options if the default ones in Workshop don't match you expectations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I tried your approach with some modifications but there were inconsistencies in count (I compared them by adding date column from object A to object B and then creating chart). And also this doesn't works if I pass the filtered object sets from workshop because the search around simply takes all the linked objects.